# Angular 7 : Modify this custom validator so that it properly checks for values greater than 1

Tags: angular7, customvalidator

In my Angular 7 application, I have made a custom validator that should check whether or not a value entered into the form control is greater than or equal to 2.

My custom validator:

```
static greaterThanOne(control: AbstractControl) {
  const v = control.value;
  if ( v >= 2) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { greaterThanOne: true };
  }
}
```

My HTML

```
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <label class="sr-only" for="dependency-section-2-3"> How many people are in the
        household?</label>
      <input
        required
        maxlength=2
        numericOnly
        formControlName="studentHouseHold"
        name="studentHouseHold"
        id="studentHouseHold"
        class="form-check-input"
        data-hint="yes"
        type="text"
        class="form-control col-4"
        data-hint="yes"
        value=""
      >
      <div *ngIf="sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.errors && sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.touched"
        class="alert text-danger m-0 p-0 col-md-12">
        <div
          *ngIf="sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.touched && sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.invalid && sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.errors.greaterThanOne && sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.errors.earningsFormat && !sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.errors.required"
          class="alert text-danger m-0 p-0 col-md-12">
          Invalid entry.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="sectionTwo.studentHouseHold.errors.required">This field is required.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Some things to note...
I cannot change the input type from "text" to "number".  To handle that, I've made a custom directive "numericOnly" that only allows the user to enter numbers.  I just need to modify the custom validator so that whatever value the user enters, must be greater than or equal to 2.

I've also tried adding angulars validator, Validator.min(2) to my form control, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, this was actually the correct way to write the validator:

```
static greaterThanOne(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
  const isValidNum = (/^([2-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-9]|9[0-9])$/).test(control.value);
  return isValidNum ? null : { greaterThanOne: true };
}
```

Hopefully this helps if anyone has encounted a similar issue.